# NameError: name 'image_id' is not defined

Tags: python, функции, случайные-числа

```
from random import randint as r
def image_info(**dictionary):
    if image_id not in dictionary or image_title not in dictionary:
        raise TypeError("Name 'image_id' or 'image_title' is not defined")
    return f"Изображение {dictionary[image_title]} имеет id {dictionary[image_id]}"
print(image_info(image_id = r(10, 999), image_title = f'image_{r(100,999)}'))
```

Comment: Не можешь перевести текст ошибки или какая проблема?

Comment: Перевести то могу, только это мне ничего не даёт.

Comment: Вместо return print написал, это я вижу, чисто случайность

Comment: Но с остальным то что не так?

Comment: Что ничего не даёт? Не можешь понять смысла написанного в ошибке? Ну вбей в гугл, даже на этом сайте примерно 100500 ответов на эту тему.

Comment: При чем тут return и print?  Как они связаны с ошибкой???

Comment: Ну а ты типа ответить нормально не можешь?
Я знаю перевод, я знаю смысл ошибки (вернее, считаю, что знаю, учитывая, что сейчас я проблему понять не могу), и если поставить 2 звёздочки перед аргументом в функции, то при вызове функции можно ввести неограниченное количество значений для именованных аргументов, что тут не так?
Блин, ты не можешь просто нормально ответить?

Comment: При чем тут return и print? Как они связаны с ошибкой???

Конкретно с этой ошибкой — никак, но это уже другая ошибка, о наличии которой я и так знаю и которую и так исправил

Comment: "нормально ответить"? А на что тут нормально отвечать? Ты никакого вопроса не задал.

Comment: Вот, блин, клоун
Я ожидал от StackOverflow нормальных вопросов/ответов, а не клоунов, которые вместо того, чтобы нормально отвечать, пишут дичь в комментарии

Comment: Клоун - это ты. Если ожидал нормальных вопросов, то и задай нормальный вопрос.

Comment: Я задал нормальный вопрос, сударь. Это ты тут пишешь дичь.

Comment: Это ты его дубликатом сделал? Там абсолютно другая проблема, сударь.

Comment: Ещё раз: у тебя было 12 часов, чтобы нормально описать свою проблему. Ты этого не осилил.

Comment: Я нормально описал свою проблему с самого начала. И человек ниже каким-то образом её понял.

Comment: Ты вообще не описал проблему. На вопрос свой посмотри для начала.

Comment: Если написана ошибка и дан код программы, то очевидно, что нужно исправить, блин, эту ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вариант:

```
from random import randint as r
def image_info(**dictionary):
    if 'image_id' not in dictionary.keys() or 'image_title' not in dictionary.keys() :
        raise TypeError("Name 'image_id' or 'image_title' is not defined")
    return f"Изображение {dictionary['image_title']} имеет id {dictionary['image_id']}"
print(image_info(image_id = r(10, 999), image_title = f'image_{r(100,999)}'))
```

Вывод:

```
 Изображение image_973 имеет id 651
```

Comment: Почему минусим? Есть ошибка покажи в чем.

Comment: Ты просто добавил .keys()? Что ж, ладно.

Comment: "Почему минусим? Есть ошибка покажи в чем." — это не ко мне вопросы, а, я так понимаю, к Эникейщику.

Comment: Закомментируй последнюю строку

Comment: |`Закомментируй последнюю` строку -print что-ли? ` Ты просто добавил .keys()?` -нет еще кавычки поставил.

Comment: "Изображение image_973 имеет id 651" — при запуске кода с этой строкой он не будет работать

Comment: Это вывод результата.

Comment: Я знаю. Просто стоило бы его либо закомментировать, либо написать отдельно от блока кода.

Comment: `.keys()` не нужен, это не питонично

Comment: А что питонично? По крайней мере, проблему .keys() решило, но если есть решение лучше, я не откажусь.

Comment: @Human проблему решили кавычки, а не .keys()

Comment: 'image id' и 'image_title'? Я ведь такое даже пробовал уже...

Comment: @Human Значит плохо пробовали )  `in dictionary.keys()` и `in dictionary` питоном обрабатывается абсолютно одинаково